# Know the time of the shutdowns of the server using GUI

Tags: windows-server-2008

One of my servers is shutting down randomly (we think power issue)

I am using the below command to get the dates of the shut down `Get-EventLog System | Where-Object {$_.EventID -eq "1074" -or $_.EventID -eq "6008" -or $_.EventID -eq "1076"} | ft Machinename, TimeWritten, UserName, EventID, Message -AutoSize -Wrap`

however I am looking for an internal or even a third party GUI app that gives me some user friendly data about the times and the reasons of shut down.

Comment: What about the builtin event log viewer?

Comment: i have the same issue last year. HP PCs shutdown itself randomly without any event log. nothing to troubleshooting at all. this year the issue is gone somehow. i found out later it was usb related issue. usb ports on HP boxes sucks, causing problems all the time

Answer (score 2):

Search for relevant events in Event Viewer. E.g `6006`, `1074`, etc. You can even make pre-defined filter logs so you only have to look at that one log and not constantly re-make your filters.

Comment: how to make a predefined filter?

Comment: @tony9099 In `eventvwr`, right click the System log and choose "Create custom view".  Add the IDs you want, click OK and name it.  You now have persistent, custom filtered event log view.